# Ransack search through scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, ransack

I have a model `Task` with a scope named `done`.
A `Task` belongs to a `Project` and to a `User`.

I need to filter users by projects in which they have a done `task`.

```
simple_form_for @q do |form|
  form.input :tasks_done_project_id, collection: Project.ordered
```

But using "_done" doesn't work.

I thought about a ransacker:

```
  ransacker :done do |parent|
    parent.done.table[:id]
  end
```

But doesn't work neither. Any Idea?

Comment: what to do if we have a scope that takes in multiple parameters. how to settle this in form? how to pass multiple parameters from form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#authorization-whitelistingblacklisting):

> By default, searching and sorting are authorized on any column of your model and no class methods/scopes are whitelisted.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> # `ransackable_scopes` by default returns an empty array
> # i.e. no class methods/scopes are authorized.
> # For overriding with a whitelist array of *symbols*.
> #
> def ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
>   []
> end
> ```

In your `Task` model, you must explicitly whitelist the `done` scope:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :done, -> { ... }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:done]
  end
end
```